How to add subview and handle its navigation in flutter
I am quite new in flutter. I was trying to clone 'canva' editing UI.
There the whole UI can be divided into 2 parts, left panel and editing area.
The left panel contains several options and upon clicking it. It navigates to corresponding subpage with a back button. the view is updated only inside the left panel as it is a sub-App. the editing area remain unaffected.

After clicking 'see all'

this is the basic structure I created.
Widget build(BuildContext context){
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Row(
      children : [
        Container(
          width : 200,
          child: Leftpanel()
        )
        Expanded(
          child: Rightpanel()
        )
      ]
    )
  )
 );
}

How should I create the navigation on the left panel with backbutton?
I am using Go-route package till now, but not sure how to handle this sub navigation.

Try to implement this static side menu.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StaticSideMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Screen'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                Flexible(
                  child: StaticDrawer(),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: PageView(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      MainContent(1),
                      MainContent(2),
                      MainContent(3),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainContent extends StatelessWidget {
  final int indexContent;

  MainContent(this.indexContent);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text('Content # $indexContent'),
      ),
      color: Colors.black26,
    );
  }
}

class StaticDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(title: Text("Menu A"), dense: true),
        ListTile(title: Text("Menu B"), dense: true),
        ListTile(title: Text("Menu C"), dense: true),
        ListTile(title: Text("Menu D"), dense: true),
        ListTile(title: Text("Menu E"), dense: true),
        ListTile(title: Text("Menu F"), dense: true),
        ListTile(title: Text("Menu G"), dense: true),
        ListTile(title: Text("Menu H"), dense: true),
        ListTile(title: Text("Menu I"), dense: true),
        ListTile(title: Text("Menu J"), dense: true),
        ListTile(title: Text("Menu K"), dense: true),
        ListTile(title: Text("Menu L"), dense: true),
        ListTile(title: Text("Menu M"), dense: true),
      ],
    );
  }
}


It is just a side panel. main question was how to move content inside the side panel similar to the navigating pages.  look images for reference. when you click on "see all " button, the entire thing inside the panel moves, like changing pages in an App.
